# Change background position when scrolled to bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background, background-position

hi I need my background position to go up 50px when the page is scrolled all the way to the bottom. Any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   //Checking if scrolled to the bottom
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       //Adding background position CSS property to the desired element
       $('.YOUR-ELEMENT-CLASS').css('background-position', '0 50px');
   }

   else {
       $('.YOUR-ELEMENT-CLASS').css('background-position', 'default_values');
   }
});
```

Comment: Isn't this going to push it DOWN?

Comment: you should set background-position to '0 -50px' so the background goes up

Comment: @unobf wtf it doesn't matter, the OP will be inserting what he wants there :). The main thing is to check when the page is scrolled to bottom. What else shall I do for him, maybe optimize his app for the search engines, connect via TeamViewer and manually change it to his needs whilst he's smoking a cigar and having a sip of 20 old whiskey?

Comment: attention to details :-P just sayin

Comment: Lol...what are you doing on Stackoverflow then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68081/discussion-between-unobf-and-knitevision).

Comment: thanks this worked, but with -50px, how will i get my background-position to go back to its original value once you scroll back up?

Comment: forgot to mention my bg-pos in css is 'center bottom' can you add pixels when its set to that?

Comment: @SamJones did you play with it? I am not a telepath, you may wanna add like "center -50px", in the script is the same CSS property that you got in your CSS.

Comment: when i add just '0 50px the script works but obviously messes my background up cos in my css its 'centre bottom' when i add like 'centre bottom 0 50px' or what you said nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want your background position to be but say it's 0 100px, you want it to go up to 50px and assuming that your element has an id of #wrapper you would do something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       $('#wrapper').css('background-position', "0 50px");
   }
});
```

Comment: Ah sorry, I started writing this and didn't see you post your answer.

Answer (score -2):

Here is also another method to do so...

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if (  document.documentElement.clientHeight + 
      $(document).scrollTop() >= document.body.offsetHeight )
{ 
    //add here your CSS code for changing color and do whatever you want
}
 });
```

I know this is same code with previous one but i also want to contribute an answer to Stack Overflow!